# unable to redirect output message in windows command prompt (cmd.exe)

Tags: windows, cmd, io-redirection

I tried to run the following command in Windows command prompt.

```
abc.exe >log.txt 2>&1
```

I'm expecting all output from `abc.exe` to be directed to `log.txt`, but it doesn't work, as the `log.txt` is empty.

However, if I just execute `abc.exe`, the output is showing up in Windows command prompt.

I'm not sure what is the output handler used by this application (STDOUT or STDERR), but I'm wondering is there a way to capture all messages regardless of the handler.

Comment: `perl abc.exe >log.txt 2>&1` try this

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" what do you mean?  The program doesn't run at all?  It runs, but there's no output?  It runs, but the output goes to the console?

Comment: Hi Johnston, it does generate the file, but it is empty. the output doesn't go to console

Comment: Hi Run, it doesn't work, and i don't understand the rational of your approach

Comment: It sounds as if a bug in the program is making it crash when the output is redirected.  Have you contacted the vendor?

Comment: What do you see when typing `abc.exe >con 2>&1`?

Answer (score 1):

*Addendum:* as of Windows 10 v1809, Windows [finally supports pseudoconsoles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session).  If available, this offers a better solution than using the legacy console API.

---

If you really need to capture that message, use the [console API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions).

`CreateConsoleScreenBuffer` and `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer` allow you to switch to a dedicated screen buffer to avoid interfering with the existing one.

`SetConsoleScreenBufferSize` can make the buffer wide enough to avoid line rollover.

`SetConsoleCursorPosition` can set the cursor position as required.

After you've run the program, `ReadConsoleOutput` allows you to read what it wrote to the console.

You can then use `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)` and `SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer` to return the console to the original buffer, and `CloseHandle` to close your extra buffer.

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys. It turns out Jonston is right, the vender admitted it is a bug in this program, which causes message couldn't redirect correctly. however, it seems weird to me that the error can be printed out to the windows console, but no way for us to capture it programmatically.

Comment: "it's a feature, not a bug": `(echo hello & echo world>con)>file.txt` echoes `world` to the screen, and you are only able to "capture" `hello` to the file. This way you can ensure, the user can see critical messages on the screen, even when a code block or even the whole script is redirected.

Comment: @Stephan, not in this particular case: the program in question wasn't generating *any* output when output was redirected, not even to the console.  The code probably assumed that standard output was a console handle (and made use of console-specific API calls) rather than opening a console handle themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The symptom that console output is not visible when redirected to a file can be due to a missing `flush()` in the program that writes to the standard output. However, the output should be visible when the program exits (gracefully) or when the respective buffer fills up and is flushed automatically.