# Python for Maya: Detect CTRL+S and then emulate a Return keystroke

Tags: python-2.7, maya, keystroke

I need a Python script that runs in the background (or ideally, within Maya) and that does the following:

1. Script is running
2. I press <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd>, script detects it
3. Script emulates a <kbd>Return</kbd> keystroke
4. Script is running

Currently, following some answers here and there, I can successfully detect the <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> keystrokes. I tried following [this answer to emulate a keystroke with WScript.Shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/136780/359408), but was unsuccessful.

**What I'm still missing:** Emulating a Return keystroke (i.e. step 3), right after the script has detected a <kbd>CTRL+S</kbd> keystroke.

My code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import win32com.client as comclt

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.comboKeys = False
        self.enterKey = False


    def keyPressed(self,event):
        print "--"

        # if Esc is pressed, stop script
        if event.keysym == 'Escape':
            root.destroy()

        # if CTRL+S is pressed
        elif event.keysym == 's':
            self.comboKeys = True


    def keyReleased(self,event):
        if event.keysym == 's':
            self.comboKeys = False


    def task(self):
        if self.comboKeys:
            print 'CTRL+S key pressed!'

        root.after(20,self.task)

application = App()
root = tk.Tk()
print( "Press arrow key (Escape key to exit):" )

root.bind_all('', application.keyPressed)
root.bind_all('', application.keyReleased)
root.after(20,application.task)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you very much! And please do let me know if I missed any sort of information.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to use Tkinter  with maya

Comment: Because it will not interface well with maya. Use QT or the builting gui framework. Remember your not building a gui for a software, your just building part of an gui inside another gui being able to interact with that other gui is important

Comment: Hmm, got it. Do you have any alternatives in mind? Problem is, I'm running on a tight deadline and I felt like this script was almost finished.

Comment: Why not use mayas own hotkey facility?

Comment: Because, as far as I know, I cannot emulate keystrokes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35024/discussion-between-joojaa-and-cr0z3r)

Answer (score 0):

If you're commited to TK and you need to run it but not to interact with Maya directly, you can just fire off a separate process with your TK applications and talk to it via the maya command port, or by using a library like [rpyc](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) to send events to Maya. It's a pain, because you have to serialize communications back and forth.

It might help us if you were more clear on what's going on inside the app. Is it text entry you're trying to do?

Comment: Hey, thanks. **Problem is:** I use Maya 2014 (Student version), which pops up a "this was created with the student version" message every time I save, auto-save, and for every reference(s) I have in my scene. My current scene has a reference in it, so it pops-up that student-message box twice. This is incredibly slowing down my workflow.. so I thought: Detect CTRL+S then emulate 2 Return keystrokes. That's what I want to do. @joojaa Helped me with this: http://pastie.org/8218563 which I call from Maya, but I'm not sure whether that script is already doing something/being run.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks for that. But I would like to create this myself (for learning purposes also). Any way you could help me out? I would like to see whether my os.system("path_to_file") call is doing something. I can see a DOS window open-close quickly, but perhaps I could print "script running" somewhere? Thank you!

Comment: the dos window proves that your system call is getting fired, but you dont get much back from it.  You might try using python's subprocess module instead, which will let you capture the output of the other tool and any return codes that come back from it.  Some examples here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406532/python-subprocess-output-on-windows