# Compile c++ with subproccess

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't seem to get the output from running the compiled file on mac but it works on windows for some reason.

**test.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Python**

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r"/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall", "-o", "test", 'test.cpp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(["test"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

Just return empty output :

```
(b'', b'')
```

Is there something I need to do extra to run on mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compilation went fine, it had no problems with your code, hence no output:

```
('', '')
```

Since you're using a POSIX system, a Mac, you tried to execute the binary without specifying './' in front of the generated binary file `test`. Hence, your command should really be:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["./test"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#                      ^^
p.communicate()
```

This should give you:

```
('Hello world\n', '')
```

As expected.

Another thing to note is that if you've added the binary's location to the `$PATH` shell variable, you wouldn't need to type `./test`. However, because the binary isn't in the `$PATH`, the shell couldn't find the executable - which is why you needed to specify the location of the binary **relative to the script's executing directory.

But, note that if you're doing this for cross-platform development (i.e. including support for Windows), that approach won't work - **your approach will - i.e. using just the *binary name* but you'll have to change the paths of where the compiler is installed**. If you're using Cygwin, then the approach shown above, will also work. If Mingw or VS, just the executable name will suffice, like in this example:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\gcc\\bin\\g++.exe", "-Wall", "-o", "test.exe", 'test.cpp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(["test.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#                    
p.communicate()
```

Reference:

[Python subprocess output on windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406532/python-subprocess-output-on-windows)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's _exactly_ the same as the top-voted answer _and_ was written earlier.

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: I am chilled. I am simply commenting on voting etiquette, is all.

Comment: Thanks, quick extra question. How to I send in input that "cin >> a" is reading for example after start ?

Comment: @ArniReynir: After the binary is run, all output is captured and stored in the `p.communicate()`. The only way to output that information will be in the binary itself. Why? Because the child process output will be captured and anything output after `p.communicate()` will be out of sync with the output of the program. It's easier and better to put that information in the binary.

Answer (score 1):

In Mac and other UNIX based operating systems, to execute a file you have to precede a file name with `./`.

So to execute the file named `test` you would have to say: `./test`

using this knowledge, your code should be modified to the following:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([r"/usr/bin/g++", "-Wall", "-o", "test", 'test.cpp'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
p = subprocess.Popen(["./test"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```